# How secure is $\operatorname{AES256}_{\operatorname{ECB}}(\operatorname{ChaCha20}(\text{plaintext}))$?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, stream-cipher, modes-of-operation, chacha

Suppose I encrypt a bytestream using ChaCha20, and then encrypt the resulting ciphertext using AES in ECB mode.  How secure is the combination?

Comment: That is called XE mode, it has good provable security properties

Comment: @RichieFrame how much stronger than ChaCha20 or AES-CTR seperately?

Comment: Strong enough that any block cipher modes I have designed in the last few years are either XE or XEX type. You get the parallelization of both modes, but eliminate their weaknesses. You can drop ChaCha to 8 rounds, and use AES-128 for additional performance

Comment: @RichieFrame Could we (or preferably, you) answer this by pointing out some kind of paper that explaints or mentions the security properties of XE mode?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I looked for the reference I was expecting, but only found the one relating to OCB mode. The reference I was expecting was much earlier

Comment: @RichieFrame and still get 256 bit security with a large margin?

Comment: @Demetri If it wouldn't then it would be considered broken. The security would probably not be degraded to a practical amount, but that's not required for theoretical attacks.

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2963/is-ecb-mode-secure-if-plaintexts-guaranteed-to-be-unique